# sort and matching the list using linq

Tags: linq

I'm having two lists.

```
List A      List B
  a          10
  b           5
  c          20
```

I have to sort the **List B** ascending. **Based on List B, List A also should reorder**. So my result will be like this

```
List A      List B
 c          20
 a          10
 b          5
```

I'm using Linq here (orderby). Facing problem in sorting the other list. How can i do this?

Comment: I think your result shows that the List B is sorted not using int but by by considering it as string..is it correct sort result that you sampled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be

```
List<string> listA = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
List<int> listB = new List<int> { 10, 5, 20 };

var joined = listA.Select((value, index) => Tuple.Create(value, listB[index]));

List<string> orderedListA = joined.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2)
                                  .Select(t => t.Item1)
                                  .ToList();
```

**Edit:** I've missed the Zip method. The line

```
 var joined = listA.Select((value, index) => Tuple.Create(value, listB[index]));
```

could be written as

```
 var joined = listA.Zip(listB, (s,i) => Tuple.Create(s,i));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `Zip` operator:

```
List<char> unsortedA = ...
List<int> unsortedB = ...

var orderedTuples = unsortedA.Zip(unsortedB, Tuple.Create)
                             .OrderByDescending(tuple => tuple.Item2)
                             .ToList();

// If required:
var sortedA = orderedTuples.ConvertAll(tuple => tuple.Item1);
var sortedB = orderedTuples.ConvertAll(tuple => tuple.Item2);
```

On another note, it appears like you should be using a tuple-type to store a character and an index together, rather than 'associating' them based on index.

Answer (score 1):

With .Net 4.0 Zip and Anonymous types

```
b.Zip(a, (x,y)=>new {Key=x, Value=y}).
  OrderBy(x=>x.Key).
  Select(x=>x.Value).
  ToList()
```